# Rewrite rule takes in two variables and adds text to the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've created an htaccess file for my website that converts a URL like this `http://www.example.com/fixture?id=1` to something like `http://www.example.com/fixtures/1`.

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^fixtures/(\d+)*$ fixture.php?id=$1
```

That works how I want it, but isn't exactly SEO friendly, so I'd like to pass in two more variables `home` and `away` like so `http://www.example.com/fixture?id=1&home=Arsenal&away=Chelsea`.

Then rewrite the URL to look like `http://www.example.com/fixtures/arsenal-vs-chelsea.

There are many questions about rewrite rules on SO, but none discuss adding a small portion of text between variables. How could I make it so that I could add the `vs` portion of the URL using a rewrite rule?

Comment: No ID in the URL and 1 in the rewrite ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^fixtures/([^/]+)-vs-([^/]+)/?$ fixture.php?home=$1&away=$2
```

Rewrite to:
`http://www.example.com/fixture?home=Arsenal&away=Chelsea`